# HMHomeDelegate and HMHomeManager Protocol's call back method is not being called:HomeKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.1, ios-homekit

I am using HomeKit apis in my iOS application.

I am facing very weird issue whenever I do **Add/Delete**  **Home/Room/Acccessory/ActionSet**

- No callback method is getting called of `HMHomeDelegate` protocol.
- Except the `homeManagerDidUpdateHomes` method no other callback method is getting called of `HMHomeManagerDelegate` protocol.

And I have set delegate properly.

I have gone through a stack over link having the same issue.

[here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26880867/hmhomemanager-didaddhome-not-returned)

Please suggest if anybody faced the similar problem.

Comment: have you set your controller as delegate of `HMHomedelgate`.

Comment: Off-course i have set delegate @Krishna